# Why is $+1$ necessary in the definition of the $\lt$-minimum element of a set of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question pertains to this paragraph in Schimmerling's "Intro to Set Theory," page 34.

> > If $A$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, then $A$ has an $\lt$-minimum element. To justify the definition, use that fact that $A\subseteq \text{sup}(A)+1$ and $(\text{sup}(A)+1,\lt)$ is a wellordering.

Why do you need the $+1$?

My guess is to deal with, for example, $A=\{1, 2,\dots\}$, where $\text{sup}(A)=\omega$, but $\omega\notin A$.

If this is a correct guess, why is $A$ any more of a subset of $\omega+1$ than $\omega$, and why is $(\omega+1,\lt)$ any more of a wellordering than $(\omega,\lt)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A=\{0,1,2\}$. Then $\sup A=2$, but $A\not\subseteq 2=\{0,1\}$. This is why you need $(\sup A)+1$.

Comment: It doesn't affect the minimum of $A$. The point of $(\sup A)+1$ is to show $\inf A$ exists in the first place. You know that any subset of a well-ordered set has a minimum. So to prove $\inf A$ exists, you need to show $A$ is a subset of a well-ordered set. The particular well-ordered set your book chose was $\sup A + 1$. You cannot choose $\sup A$, since $A\not\subseteq \sup A$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

We want an ordinal $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$. So for $A=\{2,17,42\}$, we cannot take $B=43$, we must take $B=42$ so that $42\in B$. Recall that we only know that $x\le \sup A$ for all $x\in A$, we do not know $x<\sup A$.

Comment: Maybe you would like to say the opposite? We need to take $43$ because then $42\in43$. Otherwise it fails.